# How to get roles array from Authorize Attribute of certain action in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

Suppose I have following Controller and action with authorization Attribute:

```
    public class IndexController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Index/

        [Authorize(Roles="Registered")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

I've searched over the entire Internet and not found an answer for this simple question: how to get the roles annotated to an especific Action/Controller? In this case: Index Action has: string[] = {"Registered"}

Comment: From where do you want to get those roles?

Comment: I have a Login controller to check if user is logged and I need a way to check if user is in role of returnURL! I know this is not the best way... Which is best approach to do this?

Comment: You didn't answer my question: where do you want to perform this check?

Comment: I found the solution :) I need extend the AuthorizeAttribute class and override OnAuthorization() method ;) Sorry for my ignorance! I'm a newbie in ASP.NET! I came from Java World recently!

Answer (score 5):

Finally I found the solution! Was more easy than  I thought! ahahha I need extend a class from AuthorizeAttribute and use it in actions. The information I need is the attribute "Roles" of the inherited class:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

        var roles = this.Roles;

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

}
```

And on Index Controller:

```
public class IndexController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Index/

        [CustomAuthorizationAttribute(Roles = "Registered")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

Comment: But, then how do you access the roles in the action or view?

Comment: This is wrong and not secure at all